# WinRT/C++ issue with concurrent MIDI and BLE communication

Tags: windows, bluetooth, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, midi

My team has been struggling with a pretty strange issue while using the WinRT/C++ APIs for Windows to connect to both a MIDI port and receive BLE notifications through a proprietary service on the same device.

The WinRT/C++ library itself is really nice and provides easy and modern C++ interfaces to access the managed Windows runtime classes.

I've pushed a [sample repo](https://github.com/dingari/winrt-midi-test) to Github where we've replicated the issue with a minimal example.

The repo's readme goes over the problem in detail, but I'll post the relevant bits here for completeness.

The sample program is performing roughly these steps:

- Check for available MIDI devices using a [DeviceWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-19041).
- Check for available Bluetooth LE devices using another instance of a DeviceWatcher.
- Match discovered MIDI and BluetoothLE devices on their ContainerId property (see [DeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties) for details). This is the method JUCE employs in the [native WinRT code](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_audio_devices/native/juce_win32_Midi.cpp) for their library, and works as expected.
- Open the MIDI port and attach a handler to the [MessageReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.midi.midiinport.messagereceived?view=winrt-19041) event ([see the code](https://github.com/dingari/winrt-midi-test/blob/e1f0037db039cb8be4ae5be23220c3813695a76d/Source/MainComponent.h#L67)).
- This causes the system to create a connection to the Bluetooth LE device. The program detects this state change, creates a BluetoothLEDevice, we perform GATT service discovery and attach a handler to the [ValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.valuechanged?view=winrt-19041) event for the characteristic we're interested in notifications from ([see the code](https://github.com/dingari/winrt-midi-test/blob/e1f0037db039cb8be4ae5be23220c3813695a76d/Source/MainComponent.h#L189)).

The program then counts how many MIDI messages are received on each port and how many BLE notifications are received from the corresponding device.

The behaviour we notice is that data from the most recently connected device streams just fine, while the throughput for the others is severly limited. We are at quite a standstill regarding this issue, and are not sure where the problem may lie.

We are at quite a standstill here. I'd be more willing to accept it if all the devices would exhibit this behaviour, but that's not the case. Is there any reason that creating both a MidiInPort and an BluetoothLEDevice from the same peripheral should cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A BLE radio can only receive or send at any given time. And therefore only communicate with one device at any given time. It uses a scheduler to allocate radio time for every device when you have many devices. That way a second connection can "interrupt" a connection event from another device, decreasing the throughput for that device. See https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/sds_s132/SDS/s1xx/multilink_scheduling/central_connection_timing.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

While that's a good hunch, I'm hesitant to accept that as the root cause. We are developing cross-platform software and the MacOS version does not exhibit this behaviour (even on the same hardware). There has to be something in the Windows runtime that we are either misunderstanding, or is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Use a BLE sniffer then to see what really happens in the air. And what connection interval do you have by the way?